# Creating a concatenated field with conditions, changing a numeric field to 4 digits

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression, string, concatenation

Starting from a table with fields:

"ID" (14 digit string)

"COND" (numeric)

"CDC1" (1 digit string)

"CDC2" (1 digit string)

The goal is to concatenate with an Expression these four fields, but the COND field should have a length of 4 digits once concatenated. In other words, it would have to be filled with zeros as follows:

If the "COND" field is '1' (1 digit), 3 zeros would have to be added to the left

If the "COND" field is '12' (2 digits), 2 zeros should be added  to the left

If the "COND" field is '123' (3 digits), 1 zero should be added  to the left

If the "COND" field is '1234' (4 digits), It will not be necessary to fill with zeros

I add a screenshot with the result of concatenating manually the correct way how the concatenated field would look like in these cases:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`lpad()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#lpad) function to change `COND` field value to 4 digits/characters (using `0` as fill character to the left) and use [pipes operator `||`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat) to concatenate:

```
ID || lpad (COND,4,0) || CDC1 || CDC2
```

If you have fields with `NULL` values and you want to avoid getting a concatenated string of `NULL`, better use [`concat()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concat) to concatenate only fields with values not NULL:

```
concat(ID,lpad(COND,4,0),CDC1,CDC2)
```

[image]

Comment: I confirm that your proposed Expression works perfectly. Just a correction. In my project, the last concatenated field would be "CDC2".

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the error

Answer (score 3):

Update your field CONCATENATE via Field Calculator with:

```
 CASE
    WHEN length("COND")=1 THEN "ID" || '000'|| "COND" ||"CDC1"|| "CDC2"
    WHEN length("COND")=2 THEN "ID" || '00'|| "COND" ||"CDC1"|| "CDC2"
    WHEN length("COND")=3 THEN "ID" || '0'|| "COND" ||"CDC1"|| "CDC2"
    WHEN length("COND")=4 THEN "ID" || "COND" ||"CDC1"|| "CDC2"
 END
```

Make sure your COND field is never empty, otherwise you need to catch that as well and fill it with zeros:

```
WHEN "COND" is NULL THEN "ID" || '0000' ||"CDC1"|| "CDC2"
```

Comment: Also works perfectly